# unable to install spring tools 4 (sts 4 ) on eclipse kepler - missing requirement

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I am trying to install Spring Tool Suite 4 in Eclipse Kepler using Eclipse marketplace.

I am getting the following error when trying to install :

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Cloud Foundry Manifest Language Server Feature 4.1.0.201812201040 (org.springframework.tooling.cloudfoundry.manifest.ls.feature.feature.group 4.1.0.201812201040)
  Missing requirement: Language Server Protocol client for Eclipse IDE (Incubation) 0.7.0.201809061243 (org.eclipse.lsp4e 0.7.0.201809061243) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.12.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Cloud Foundry Manifest Language Server Feature 4.1.0.201812201040 (org.springframework.tooling.cloudfoundry.manifest.ls.feature.feature.group 4.1.0.201812201040)
    To: org.eclipse.lsp4e 0.6.0

i have tried to install Language Server Protocol but i can't find him in marketplace or google

My Eclipse version is Kepler Service Release 2

Java version : Java 8

Spring Plugin link : https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-spring-boot-aka-spring-tool-suite-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that the plug-in `org.eclipse.core.runtime` with a version of at least 3.12.0 is required. Eclipse Kepler only has version 3.9 of this plug-in.

So Eclipse Kepler is too old for this install (it is 10 releases and 6 years out of date). You will need to use an up to date version of Eclipse for this code - Eclipse 2019-09 is the current version.